# How to access Algolia index and search properties?

Tags: ios, swift, algolia

I'm a iOS Swift dev using Swift 5 and I just updated my Algolia pod from `pod 'AlgoliaSearch-Client-Swift', '~> 5.0'` to 
`pod 'InstantSearchClient', '~> 7.0'`.

I changed the headers from `import AlgoliaSearch` to `import InstantSearchClient`

Once I did that I no longer had access to the Algolia data type:

[image]

The [docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/search/#examples) says:

```
let index = client.index(withName: "contacts")
index.search(Query(query: "s"), completionHandler: { (content, error) -> Void in
  if error == nil {
      print("Result: \(content!)")
  }
})
```

No where on that page does it say what the `datatype` of `client` is so I took a wild guess and used: `var index: Client!` which worked. I'm a little perplexed as to why that page doesn't say anything about `Client` being a datatype.

Anyway now that I have access to the `Client` I no longer have access to the `index` or `search` properties:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**How do I access the `index` and `search` properties?**

Here is the code:

```
// import AlgoliaSearch // this is from the old pod
import InstantSearchClient

var index: Client! // before changing the pod I used AlgoliaSearch.Index! which worked fine
let query = Query()
var searchId = 0
var loadedPage: UInt = 0
var nbPages: UInt = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let apiClient = Client(appID: "12345", apiKey: "ABC...XYZ")

    // *** error ***
    index = apiClient.index(withName: "myIndex")

    query.hitsPerPage = 15
    query.attributesToRetrieve = ["flavor", "color"]
}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    query.query = searchController.searchBar.text
    let curSearchId = searchId

    // *** error ***
    index.search(query, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, error) in
    })
}

func loadMore() {

    if loadedPage + 1 >= nbPages {
        return
    }
    let nextQuery = Query(copy: query)
    nextQuery.page = loadedPage + 1

    // *** error ***
    index.search(nextQuery, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data , error) in
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Client` was the wrong answer.

Under the old `import AlgoliaSearch` I used `AlgoliaSearch.Index` but under the new `import InstantSearchClient` I used `InstantSearchClient.Index`

Now the declaration is:

```
var index: InstantSearchClient.Index!
```

The complete code is:

```
import InstantSearchClient

var index: InstantSearchClient.Index! // this works :)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // ...
}
```